# Java MDC mixing session data

Tags: java, log4j, mdc

I am using Log4j as a logging framework. I am using MDC to hold some values across application so that when finally do log and get those inside eventhelpers. But in case of error/Exception logs on server I noticed that other session values are getting mix up.

Like DeptId what need to be logged is not there whereas other is logged.

Is MDC not thread-safe? any solution to this?

example

```
MDC.put("prsn_id","123456");
MDC.put("dept_id","comp_sc_12");
```

Comment: MDCs, like NDCs, are `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: what that means, are they thread-safe?

Comment: But when session is invalidated some other session value getting logged inside logs...seems some session data is mixing when old session invalidated and new one just created after that

Comment: Then it's likely something else is wrong with your container or application. You should validate your session data outside of the DC first, then make sure the data in your session is thread-safe and current/correct, then explore potential library issues. Why'd you let it wait a year?